# Html action Element not working

Tags: html, jsp, jsp-tags

I have two files. One is `form.html` and another is `form2.jsp`

I want to process `form2.jsp` by using form action element in the `form.html`, but after clicking on submit in `form.html`, the action element is not working. Both files are in the same directory i.e. WebContent folder in webapplication.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
      <title>Registration Form</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form name="form" action="form2.jsp" method="get">
         First Name : <input type="text" name="fname">
         Last Name : <input type="text" name="lname">
         <input type ="button" value="Submit" />
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
      <title>Insert title here</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <%
         out.println("Hello from form2'");
      %>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this,

```
<input type ="button" value="Submit" />
```

With

```
<input type ="submit" value="Submit" />
```

or with

```
<button type="submit">Submit</Button>
```